# Dynamic/Editable MVC routes stored in the database for blog engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm planning to write an MVC blog engine, supporting multiple blogs. When creating a blog the user will be able to choose the path where his blog will be accessed.

For example:

/blogs/**firstBlog**/

/newprojects/**secondBlog**/

/foo/bar/**thirdblog**/

This route information will be stored in the database. Instead of MVC using only the routes statically declared in Global.asax.cs, I'd like it to read the routes from the database first. Then if it doesn't find anything, fallback on the routes declared in Global.asax.cs. Is this possible? If yes what would you suggest to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd declare your default route as normal, and then read the database and call the same methods, but rather than passing in hard coded strings, pass in the values from the database:

```
foreach(RouteDetails routeDetails in routesFromDatabase)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        routeDetails.Name,                                             
        routeDetails.Route,
        routeDetails.Defaults);
}
```

You'll need to map the tables properly and populate the fields in the imagined object 'RouteDetails', including the `Defaults` dictionary (which would probably be the most complicated).

You can find a couple of examples here:

- [asp.net mvc: store routes in the
  database](http://www.iansuttle.com/blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-Store-Routes-in-the-Database.aspx)
- [Editable MVC Routes Apache Style](http://coderjournal.com/2010/03/editable-mvc-routes-apache-style/)